# Jekyll markdown not displaying like the original and general style problems

Tags: html, css, format, markdown, jekyll

we have a blog post written in markdown, which we would like to implement on our Jekyll page which is hosted on GithubPages.

### **Here an markdown code excerpt of the post:**

````
```python
import keras
```

**TensorFlow:**

```python
import tensorflow as tf
```

## Building the Model

**Keras:**

We can easily create linear to complex models through the [`sequential`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) API, which stacks up layers in a linear fashion. For linear regression, we can write this as follow:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation="linear", input_dim=1))
```

* Keras includes many commonly used layers:
    - Regular `dense` layers for feed-forward neural networks
    - `Dropout`, `normalization` and `noise` layers to prevent overfitting and improve learning
    - Common `convolutional` and `pooling layers` (max and average) for CNNs
    - `Flatten` layers to add fully connected layers after convolutional nets
    - `Embedding` layers for Word2Vec problems
    - `Recurrent` layers (simpleRNN, GRU and LSTM) for RNNs
    - `Merge` layers to combine more than one neural net
    - Many more… you can also [write your own Keras layers](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/)
* Many common activation functions are available like `relu`, `tanh` and `sigmoid` depending on the problem that you like to solve (read [“Yes you should understand backprop” by Andrej Karpathy](https://medium.com/@karpathy/yes-you-should-understand-backprop-e2f06eab496b) if you want to understand the effect of backpropagation on some activation functions)
* The activation function can also be passed through an `Activation` layer instead of the `activation` argument

Alternatively if you prefer one-liners, we could have also done something like this:

```python
model = Sequential([Dense(units=1, activation="linear", input_dim=1)])
```

Or we could have used [Keras’s functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/):

```python
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
````

### **Here is how it should look like (displayed on Github in a README.md):**

[image]

### **Here is how our final post.md looks on the hosted Jekyll page:**

[image]

### This is the _config.yml:

```
title: BML
email:xxx@gmail.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
  line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
  Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: xyz
github_username:  xyz
future: true
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
theme: minima
gems:
  - jekyll-feed
exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
```

We looked for hours how get this done and our results and realizations so far are:

- There doesn't seem to be a reasonable way to implement posts written in markdown into Jekyll
- The result is quite unpleasant (lists messed up, codeblocks not super nice, weird spacings and vertical distances)
- I had to implement some `syntax.css` to have the code blocks styled
- Jekyll forces us to use kramdown
- There is no easy to convert markdown to kramdown (kramdown seems to have different syntax in some places)

Also I don't really get, why e.g. lists are rendered without any style, although they are correctly registered as ul li elements in the DOM. The `list-style: none;`for the `<ul>` elements comes from some inline `<style type="text/css">` rendered into the websites head. Don't really know where it comes from, the main theme maybe? 
[image]
Without this style tag at least the list look better...

I tried things like using kramdown="1" attribute, playing around with the indents and dozens of other 'tricks' and structures.

1. Is there any easy way to have real markdown rendered like on Github?
2. How to know where this weird style tag comes from? How to exclude it?

The website which I am currently working on is: 
http://www.machinelearning.berlin

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: even though your config file shows that you're using theme `minima`, your markup screenshot shows `Arcana by HTML5 UP`.. Also **ensure there are no BOM sequences** in your files

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll is really straight forward. Unfortunately some wise people (the architects of Jekyll) decided to create themes and bundle them with every new project. That is a big mistake IMHO. This results in many people starting out with code they do not understand, and even worse, a structure they do not understand. This quote demonstrates that perfectly:

> The list-style: none; for the ul elements comes from some inline style rendered into the websites head. Don't really know where it comes from, the main theme maybe?

So this is a message for anyone who has similar problems and knows basic HTML and CSS: Jekyll is really simple. Please do not use a theme if you start with Jekyll. Start your projects empty. This approach will save you a lot of hours and frustration. Also, it will provide you with a deep understanding of what Jekyll is and how it works. You will thank me later.

PS. To answer your question: I can assure you that your mysterious code belongs to the theme you have (not) chosen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I jumped in into the project, so that I started where it was left. Would you then suggest to reset it to a "theme-less" project and do everything from scratch? Or just make everything new from scratch (the website is not that big now: http://www.machinelearning.berlin )? Would it be possible then to have nice formatted markdown like on github, without further effort?

Comment: Nothing is without effort. But if possible I would start over/clean and copy the stylesheets you need.